# PHP / Laravel 4 echo checkbox value from database stored as boolean

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-4

I have a few checkboxes that are stored as 0 for unchecked or 1 for checked as booleans.

I am now trying to echo back the values using laravel such as

```
echo $request->facebook
```

Which returns 1 or 0. It does not return the value of "facebook".

In my view I have:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="facebook" name="facebook" class="css-checkbox" />
```

In my model I have this:

```
$request->facebook = Input::has('facebook');
$request->save();
```

The model will check the form for the checkbox facebook and saves the boolean value in the database.

What is the best way to echo "facebook" if the checkbox was checked or echo out nothing, if the checkbox was unchecked?

Comment: You want to echo the string "facebook" if the checkbox was checked?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do for checkboxes in my controllers:

```
$object = new MyObject;

$object->facebook = Input::has('facebook') ? 1 : 0;
$object->twitter = Input::has('twitter') ? 1 : 0;
$object->somethingElse = Input::has('someCheckbox') ? 1 : 0;

$object->save();
```

There may be better ways to do it but this is what I typically do. It's easy to read and understand and keeps your code organized.

I've experimented with moving things like this into the model using mutators, but I was kind of unsure about using the `Input` class on the model. In your controller POST method, the `Input` class is always going to be there. There is always going to be `Input` to check and use. But on some random model method, it's possible that you may access that method someday outside of a POST request and then there is no post input, so things like `Input::has()` will return false and set those values to zero.

There may be a more elegant way to do it. I'm not sure what though.

Comment: Really just looking for the easiest way to do this, because I have a lot of checkboxes! Which means I need a ton of IF statements. That is my issue. Is boolean the right approach for checkboxes when you want to echo back the actual values?

Comment: I see what you mean, let me revise the answer.

Comment: You were asking how to set the value of an attribute based off of a checkbox, right? Can you revise your question?

Comment: You gotta be more specific on your question. You make it sound like you want the string "facebook" to be echoed out if the checkbox is checked. Where do you want it echoed? During the form submission? Or in the view?